# How can i creat a stored procedure on mirroring database using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two servers: server1 includes the primary_DB and server2 includes the mirror_DB, I created a database in another server3, then I created two servers linked to the servers 1 and 2.

The objectif is to create a stored procedure to collect data from server 1 or 2 (depending on the active databse)  and insert data into server 3 using the likned server.

I wanted create two jobs using two stored procedure, one with linked1 and second with the linked2 in case of server failover, but creation is not allowed when the database acts as a mirror database.

My question is how to retrieve data using a stored procedure from a database that can become a mirror database?

Comment: Pull your data from the active mirror rather than push it.

Comment: Stu, what do you mean, i didn't understand ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, i used Dynamic SQL on creation the stored procedure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).